# I want to encrypt TidBytes with AES

Tags: delphi, aes

I am using Tforge and Delphi and I am trying to encrypt `TidBytes` with AES

```
var Key,MyBytearray: ByteArray;
MyTidBytes:TidBytes;

Key:= ByteArray.FromText('1234567890123456');

EncryptedText:= TCipher.AES.ExpandKey(Key, CTR_ENCRYPT or PADDING_NONE).EncryptByteArray(MyBytearray);
```

This code works fine with `ByteArray` but I want to use it with idBytes is this possible?

How I will convert `ByteArray` to `TidBytes`?

Comment: TIdBytes is part of Indy networking library that ships with Delphi. Now since Indy library also offers some of its own encryption capabilites maybe you could use that instead of TCipher. Othervise based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18854367/3636228) SO answer it might be possible to typecast TIdBytes array as TBytes array since both are dynamic arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ByteArray` is declared as a `record` that internally holds an `IBytes` interfaced object wrapping the byte data. `TIdBytes` is declared as a simple dynamic array instead. As such, you can't *directly* typecast between them. You must *copy* the raw bytes back and forth.

You can do that manually, eg:

```pascal
MyBytearray := ...;
MyTidBytes := RawToBytes(MyBytearray.Raw^, MyBytearray.Len);
// RawToBytes() is an Indy function in the IdGlobal unit...

...

MyTidBytes := ...;
MyBytearray := ByteArray.FromBytes(MyTidBytes);
// FromBytes() accepts any type of raw byte array as input, including dynamic arrays ...
```

Or, alternatively, `ByteArray` has `Implicit` conversion operators for `TBytes`, and `TIdBytes` is typecast-compatible with `TBytes` as they are both dynamic arrays, eg:

```pascal
MyBytearray := ...;
TBytes(MyTidBytes) := MyBytearray;

...

MyTidBytes := ...;
MyBytearray := TBytes(MyTidBytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how `ByteArray` and `TidBytes` are declared.

---

If they are both dynamic arrays of `Byte`, you could use a [typecast](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Expressions_(Delphi)).

From `TidBytes` to `ByteArray`:

```
MyByteArray := ByteArray(MyTidBytes);
```

From `ByteArray` to `TidBytes`:

```
MyTidBytes := TidBytes(MyBytearray);
```

---

If `ByteArray` is defined like [this](https://bitbucket.org/sergworks/tforge/src/default/Source/User/tfArrays.pas) and `TidBytes` is a dynamic array of `Byte`, try the following:

```
MyByteArray.Insert(0, TBytes(MyTidBytes));
```

Comment: but i want to connvert Tidbytes to Bytearray and not the other way

Comment: @icinemagr If the cast works in one direction, surely it will work in the other direction?

Comment: No it doesnt work i try it bytearray is declared in Tfarrays.pas  here https://bitbucket.org/sergworks/tforge/src/default/Source/User/tfArrays.pas And is not working. what i am trying to do is to send the Encrypted ByteArray Thru indy UDP client. and decrypt it on IndyUDPserver but i cannot

Comment: i checked as correct because you are the only one answer me.But it Doesnt work i get exception error