# Assign a TArray to a array of T

Tags: arrays, delphi, generics

How do I assign a `TArray<Byte>` to `array of Byte` and vice versa?

`TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes` returns a `TArray<Byte>`. `TIdHashMessageDigest5.HashBytes` has a `TIdBytes = array of Byte` as parameter.

Can I assign these types to each other? Maybe with a copy? Or do I need to loop?

Comment: See also [Delphi XE4 Indy compatibility issue between TBytes and TidBytes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16343080/576719).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These types are not assignment compatible. In an ideal world you would use `TArray<T>` exclusively, and it would be better if all libraries did so. I do not understand why Indy insists on using its own distinct type here.

If you cannot then you can make a copy. That's easy enough with a loop. If efficiency matters that you could copy using `Move`.

```
SetLength(Dest, Length(Source));
Move(Pointer(Source)^, Pointer(Dest)^, Length(Source));
```

I use `Pointer(arr)^` here rather than `arr[0]` to avoid tripping range check exceptions in case of an empty array.

It is also possible to avoid a copy by using a typecast, since all dynamic arrays are implemented the same way. So you could write

```
Hash := HashBytes(TIdBytes(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(...)));
```

Of course, this gives up type safety, but then so does the call to `Move` above.

Yet another approach, suggested by [Remy's answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339656/delphi-xe4-indy-compatibility-issue-between-tbytes-and-tidbytes/16343080#16343080), is to use `TIdTextEncoding` rather than `TEncoding`. That way you can work with `TIdBytes` exclusively.

Comment: I imagine Indy does it like this for backwards compatibility with Delphi versions that do not have TArray<T>?

Comment: @penarthur66 `TIdBytes` could readily be conditionally defined to get around that.

Comment: @penarthur66 actually, `TIdBytes` used to be an alias for `TBytes` when available (which is an alias for `TArray<Byte>` when available), but doing so caused a lot of problems, especially in several event handlers across the Delphi/C++ boundary (Embarcadero RTTI bugs). So eventually I had no choice but to make `TIdBytes` go back to using `array of Byte` to maintain proper functionality. It was not to handle backwards compatibility, it was to handle Embarcadero bugs.